# linecache-0.43 gem installation issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, linecache

I am trying to do a bundle install which includes ruby-debug gem. However the installation fails with the error

linecache-0.43 has an invalid value for @cert_chain

I ma using rails 2.3.8, ruby 1.8.7 and RubyGems 1.7.1

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved this by downgrading my RubyGems from 1.7.1 to 1.6.2. Found it here

[Rails 3 install error: "invalid value for @cert_chain"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520333/rails-3-install-error-invalid-value-for-cert-chain)