# Warnings with RCov and Saikuro while installing Metrical

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, rcov, metrical

Having hard time installing some gems needed to get Metrical up and running.

```
WARNING: Saikuro-1.1.0 has an invalid nil value for @cert_chain
WARNING: rcov-0.9.9 has an invalid nil value for @cert_chain
```

Quick [Googling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520333/rails-3-install-error-invalid-value-for-cert-chain) points to a bug in gem 1.7.1, fixed in 1.7.2.

My gem system version is 1.8.5.  I am running on Rails 3.0.7, Windows 7 64-bit.  ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18) [i386-mingw32]

Please assist.  What should I do to get Saikuro and RCov installed?

Comment: Staring at http://isitruby19.com/rcov