# WARNING: builder-2.1.2 has an invalid nil value for @cert_chain

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

How do I get rid of this warning or fix it?

```
gem install rails --version=3.0.10

Fetching: activesupport-3.0.10.gem (100%)
Fetching: builder-2.1.2.gem (100%)
WARNING: builder-2.1.2 has an invalid nil value for @cert_chain
Fetching: i18n-0.5.0.gem (100%)
Fetching: activemodel-3.0.10.gem (100%)
Fetching: rack-1.2.4.gem (100%)
Fetching: rack-test-0.5.7.gem (100%)
Fetching: rack-mount-0.6.14.gem (100%)
Fetching: abstract-1.0.0.gem (100%)
WARNING: abstract-1.0.0 has an invalid nil value for @cert_chain
Fetching: erubis-2.6.6.gem (100%)
Fetching: actionpack-3.0.10.gem (100%)
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520333/rails-3-install-error-invalid-value-for-cert-chain  I had to downgrade to 1.6.2 of Rubygems to make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot fix or get rid of this warning without submitting a patch to the gem that would fix it. I do not know what is causing it, so I cannot advise on that part.

Comment: Not constructive. You contradict yourself by stating you don't know what is causing it but saying a patch will fix it.

Comment: @Coderama: I suggest submitting a patch, but I couldn't tell you *what* part of the gem to patch. That is what I meant by that answer.