# What cause the WARNING: what_methods-1.0.1 has an invalid nil value for @cert_chain

Tags: rubygems

When trying to install the gem `what_methods`, I'm getting

```
$ gem install what_methods
Fetching: what_methods-1.0.1.gem (100%)
WARNING: what_methods-1.0.1 has an invalid nil value for @cert_chain
Successfully installed what_methods-1.0.1
1 gem installed
```

I know there are currently some questions about the warning, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514331/warning-builder-2-1-2-has-an-invalid-nil-value-for-cert-chain) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520333/rails-3-install-error-invalid-value-for-cert-chain). In response, some people were saying that this is the problem of the gem.

**I'd like to know what causes the issue** and if possible how can it be fixed on the gem's side.

Answer (score 0):

From here -- http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/2216001

> This is a warning generated by RubyGems as it installs each of these gems. It just means that the gem's specification isn't following the rules that RubyGems expects. Recent versions of RubyGems have been more vocal about reporting these warnings.
>
> However, this isn't going to affect the running of your gems, so I wouldn't worry about it. The warnings will go away once the maintainers of those gems update them to fix the error in their specification.

And for more info on what "cert_chain" actually is, see -- http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/21#page88